# When use flush with JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a REST API project with Spring (5.7.2) Web / Security.

I have just one table `discs`, it contain a id, and a name.

```
public class DiscsRepository extends JpaRepository<Discs, Integer> {
}
```

When I delete a disc, my DiscsService do

```
discsRepository.deleteById(5);
```

When I want insert or update I do :

```
discsRepository.save(myDisc);
```

I read that `flush()` is used when you want use the value in same transaction (before commit) and that `flush()` will synchronize and empty the SQL cache.

In my case I see that I have the value inserted / updated or deleted in my database.

Should I use `flush()` (I think no) but maybe I mistaken ?

Answer (score 3):

The Insert, Update and Delete SQL statements are usually executed at commit.

If you want to force that you can call `flush()`.

This is for example useful if you have triggers in the database that should be executed just after you call save or delete and not wait until the commit.